# Ember.js error while loading route

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember app with two models, user and subject, both of which rely on an api for data. The JSON returned is not in the format that ember expects, so I have a custom serializer for each model-

```
var foo = {

    'App.Subject': {'single':'subject','array':'subjects'}

};

App.SubjectSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    var p = {};
    p[foo[type]['single']] = payload;
    return this._super(store, type, p, id, requestType);
  },
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    var p = {};
    p[foo[type]['array']] = payload;
    return this._super(store, type, p, id, requestType);
  },
  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(record, options));
  }
});
```

This works perfectly. However, I have a similar serializer for my Users model-

```
var foo = {

    'App.User': {'single':'user','array':'users'}

};

App.UserSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    var p = {};
    p[foo[type]['single']] = payload;
    return this._super(store, type, p, id, requestType);
  },
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    var p = {};
    p[foo[type]['array']] = payload;
    return this._super(store, type, p, id, requestType);
  },
  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(record, options));
  }
});
```

When I try to access my users in the browser, I get this error:

> Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'array' of undefined

Can anyone help?

EDIT: 'type' in the extractArray function refers to the root property of the JSON, eg if my JSON was

```
{
  "user": {
    name: "xyz",
    email: "xyz@wxy.com"
  }
}
```

the 'type' would be 'user'.

Comment: and what is 'type' in the extractArray function when the code is being executed ?, put a debugger or a log, and see what value it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mappings[type]` is undefined.  What is mappings?

BTW, there is an easier way to do this,

**single**

```
p[type.typeKey] = payload;
```

**array**

```
p[Ember.String.pluralize(type.typeKey)] = payload;
```

Comment: Sure it is, I told him where his error was. I asked him an additional question to hit 30 chars.